# ConTeXt: How to remove the gap between untitled (floatcombination) floats and outer float title

Tags: context

When using `floatcombination` inside a `startplaceFLOAT` with untitled inner floats (`location=none`) there is a gap between floats and the title, just like that:

```tex
\startTEXpage
    \startplacefigure[location={here}, title={Here is a title}]
        \startfloatcombination[nx=2, ny=1, distance=2.5cm]
            \startplacefigure[location={none}]
            \startMPcode
                draw (-1cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) ;
                draw (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,1cm) ;
            \stopMPcode
            \stopplacefigure

            \startplacefigure[location={none}]
            \startMPcode
                draw (-1cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) ;
                draw (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,1cm) ;
            \stopMPcode
            \stopplacefigure
        \stopfloatcombination
    \stopplacefigure
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

From my understanding this gap is what is left from inner floats titles

```tex
\startTEXpage
    \startplacefigure[location={here}, title={Here is a title}]
        \startfloatcombination[nx=2, ny=1, distance=2.5cm]
            \startplacefigure[location={here}]
            \startMPcode
                draw (-1cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) ;
                draw (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,1cm) ;
            \stopMPcode
            \stopplacefigure

            \startplacefigure[location={here}]
            \startMPcode
                draw (-1cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) ;
                draw (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,1cm) ;
            \stopMPcode
            \stopplacefigure
        \stopfloatcombination
    \stopplacefigure
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible with floatcombinations, but with an ordinary combination you can get what I think you are looking for (I added `\showboxes` so that we see a bit better what is there):

```
\showboxes
\starttext
    \startplacefigure[location={here}, title={Here is a title}]
        \startfloatcombination[nx=2, ny=1, distance=2.5cm]
            \startplacefigure[location={none}]
            \startMPcode
                draw (-1cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) ;
                draw (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,1cm) ;
            \stopMPcode
            \stopplacefigure

            \startplacefigure[location={none}]
            \startMPcode
                draw (-1cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) ;
                draw (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,1cm) ;
            \stopMPcode
            \stopplacefigure
        \stopfloatcombination
    \stopplacefigure
    
    \startplacefigure[location={here}, title={Here is a title}]
        \startcombination[nx=2, ny=1, distance=2.5cm]
            \startcontent
            \startMPcode
                draw (-1cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) ;
                draw (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,1cm) ;
            \stopMPcode
            \stopcontent
            \startcaption
            \stopcaption
            \startcontent
            \startMPcode
                draw (-1cm,0cm) -- (1cm,0cm) ;
                draw (0cm,-1cm) -- (0cm,1cm) ;
            \stopMPcode
            \stopcontent
            \startcaption
            \stopcaption
        \stopcombination
    \stopplacefigure
\stoptext
```

[image: combination]

Comment: I discussed this with Hans, and from the next version, it should work to use `location=none` in the float combination, as you did.

Comment: Float combination `location=none` works like a charm since yesterday update. Many thanks for having discussed about this with Hans.